# Sum of three consecutive cubes

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations

When I noticed that $3^3+4^3+5^3=6^3$, I wondered if there are any other times where $(a-1)^3+a^3+(a+1)^3$ equals another cube. That expression simplifies to $3a(a^2+2)$ and I'm still trying to find another value of $a$ that satisfies the condition (the only one found is $a=4$)

Is this impossible? (It doesn't happen for $3 \leq a \leq 10000$) Is it possible to prove?

Comment: I think you mean $a=4$, not $a=2$: $1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 = 36$ is not a cube, but $3^3 + 4^3 + 5^3 = 6^3$

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yup, I changed that :)

Comment: Have you read [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicNumber.html) article? It seems that that is the only three consecutive integers whose cubes sum to a cube.

Comment: It is also known as a Plato's number http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plato%27s_number

Comment: @Jack is it difficult to prove? I think I've read that but still tried to find one.

Comment: If you notice, $\gcd(a,a^2+2)=\gcd(a,2)$, so the only way to get $3a(a^2+2)=b^3$ is for $a=2^m\cdot3^n$ and $a^2+2=2^h\cdot3^k\cdot c^3$ with $2,3\not\mid c$ and $m+h\equiv0\equiv1+n+k\pmod3$. Perhaps you can rule out some cases (like e.g. m=0).

Comment: @bgins Why can't $a$ itself also have other cube factors?

Comment: @Jack: I saw that article before but it doesn't seem to cite the reference.

Comment: @SivaramAmbikasaran: Indeed, I didn't find the reference either. I only found it in [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=aFDWuZZslUUC&pg=PA616&lpg=PA616&dq=%22the+only+three+consecutive+integers+whose+cubes+sum+to+a+cube%22&source=bl&ots=4pbPuvEggM&sig=aWEERAG9l_mhrhk6Uyl-i5UouqQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tk1hT5qrMJHmgge2t4yfAg&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22the%20only%20three%20consecutive%20integers%20whose%20cubes%20sum%20to%20a%20cube%22&f=false) book.

Comment: @Jack Thanks. Quite interesting. I am not sure if the proof is too trivial that there is no citation.

Comment: @Arthur: You're right, it can. However, I think if it does, we can "without loss of generality" throw them away and look at the (smaller) case presented.

Comment: @bgins No, I don't think we can, since introducing cube factors to $a$ means $(a^2 + 2)$ can obtain a lot more values.

Comment: @Arthur, thanks. I addressed that in my partial answer below.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a start. If you notice, $\gcd(a,a^2+2)=\gcd(a,2)$, so
by the unique factorization theorem,
$$
\eqalign{
 & 3a(a^2+2)=z^3 \\
 & \text{is a perfect cube}
}
~\iff~
\matrix{
 a     &=& a_1^3\cdot2^{a_2}\cdot3^{a_3} \\
 a^2+2 &=& b_1^3\cdot2^{b_2}\cdot3^{b_3}
}
\quad
\text{with}
\quad
\eqalign{
 & 2,3\not\mid a_1,b_1 \\
 & a_2+b_2\equiv0\pmod3 \\
 & a_3+b_3\equiv2\pmod3,
}
$$
with all $a_i,b_i$ nonnegative except for
$a_1$, which has the same sign as $a$.
This has known solutions
$$a=0,\quad\text{for which}\quad
\mathbb{a}
=\left[\matrix{a_1\cr a_2\cr a_3}\right]
=\left[\matrix{0\cr0\cr0}\right],\quad
\mathbb{b}
=\left[\matrix{b_1\cr b_2\cr b_3}\right]
=\left[\matrix{1\cr1\cr0}\right],
\tag{solution 0}
$$
and
$$a=\pm4,\quad\text{for which}\quad
\mathbb{a}=\left[\matrix{\pm1\cr2\cr0}\right],\quad
\mathbb{b}=\left[\matrix{1\cr1\cr2}\right].
\tag{solution 1}
$$
But then for $a\ne0$, assume without loss of generality that $a>0$
(so $a_1,b_1\ge1$), and note that,
looking at the powers of two and three in its prime factorization,
$$
\eqalign{
    b_1^3\cdot2^{b_2}\cdot3^{b_3}
& = a^2+2
  = a_1^6\cdot2^{2a_2}\cdot3^{2a_3}+2 \\
& = 2 \left( a_1^6\cdot2^{2a_2-1}\cdot3^{2a_3} + 1\right)
}
$$
implies that either $a_2\ge1=b_2$ (case 2.1) or $a_2=b_2=0$ (case 2.0),
and by similar reasoning, either $a_3>0=b_3$ (case 3.1),
or else $a_3=0$ and $b_3\equiv2\pmod3$, which I will call case 3.0.
This leaves us with four combinations to check,
and hopefully either rule out or simplify:
$$
\matrix{
\\\text{case }0=2.0\wedge3.0:&\quad a_2=a_3=b_2=0 ,\quad b_3\equiv2\pmod3
\\\text{case }1=2.1\wedge3.0:&\quad a_2\ge1=b_2,\quad a_3=0,\quad b_3\equiv2\pmod3
\\\text{case }2=2.0\wedge3.1:&\quad a_3>0=a_2=b_2=b_3
\\\text{case }3=2.1\wedge3.1:&\quad a_2,a_3\ge1=b_2,\quad b_3=0.
}
$$
These four cases comprise all nontrivial
(i.e. other than solution 0), (WLOG) postivie solutions,
and we hope to deduce that only case 1 with solution 1 is viable.
Case 0 simplifies to
$$
b_1^3 \cdot 3^{b_3} = a_1^6+2
\qquad\text{for}\qquad
a_1,b_1\not\equiv0\pmod{2,3}
\quad\text{and}\quad
b_3\equiv2\pmod3.
$$
Since $b_3\ge2$,
we have $a_1^6\equiv-2\pmod9$, which has no solutions $a_1$
(sixth powers are always $0$ or $1$ modulo $9$), ruling this case out.
Case 2 simplifies to
$$
b_1^3 = a_1^6 \cdot 3^{2a_3} + 2
\qquad\text{for}\qquad
a_1,b_1\not\equiv0\pmod{2,3}
\quad\text{and}\quad
a_3 > 0,
$$
so that $b_1^3\equiv2\pmod9$, which we can also rule out,
since cubes are always $0$ or $\pm1$ modulo $9$.
Case 3 simplifies to
$$
 2b_1^3 = 2^{2a_2  } 3^{2a_3} a_1^6 + 2
= 2\left( 2^{2a_2-1} 3^{2a_3} a_1^6 + 1 \right)
\qquad\text{for}\qquad
a_1,b_1\not\equiv0\pmod{2,3}
\quad\text{and}\quad
a_2,a_3 > 1,
$$
so that $b_1^3\equiv1\pmod9\implies b_1$ is even,
a contradiction. Lastly, case 1 simplifies to
$$
 3^{b_3} \cdot b_1^3 = 2^{2a_2-1} a_1^6 + 1
\qquad\text{for}\qquad
a_1,b_1\not\equiv0\pmod{2,3},
\quad a_2 \ge 1
\quad\text{and}\quad
b_3\equiv2\pmod3.
$$
so that $b_3\ge2\implies$ $2^{2a_2-1} a_1^6\equiv-1\pmod9$
$\implies a_1^6 \equiv-2^{1-2a_2} \equiv 2^{-2(a_2+1)} \pmod 9$
since $2$ is a primitive root modulo $9$,
i.e. $\text{ord}_9(2)=6=\phi(9)$, and $2^{\pm3}\equiv-1\pmod9$.
But then $a_1\equiv2^{a_0}\pmod9$
for some $a_0$ with $-2(a_2+1)\equiv6a_0\equiv0\pmod6$,
so that $a_2+1\equiv3~\implies~a_2\equiv2\pmod6$.
In particular, we see that $a_2\ge2$.

Well anyway, that's a start.
If we could show that $a_2,b_3\le2$,
then we could reduce case 1 to $9y^3-8x^6=1$,
and our goal would be to show that
its only positive solution is $(1,1)$,
and a start at that might be to note
that $9y^3\equiv8x^6+1\equiv9\pmod{72}$.

Answer (score 7):

How about $$(-1)^3+0^3+1^3=0^3?$$

Answer (score 4):

How about 
$$\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^3 + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3 + \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^3 = \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^3 ?$$
After all, the OP didn't specify where $a$ lives... (by the way, there are infinitely many distinct rational solutions of this form!).

Now for a more enlightened answer: **no, there are no other integral solutions** with $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, other than $a=0$ and $a=4$. Here is why (what follows is a sketch of the argument, several details would be too lengthy to write fully).

Suppose $(a-1)^3+a^3+(a+1)^3=b^3$. Then $3a^3+6a=b^3$. Hence $(a:b:1)$ is a point on the elliptic curve $E:3Z^3+6ZY^2=X^3$ with origin at $(0:1:0)$. In particular, a theorem of Siegel tells us that there are at most finitely many integral solutions of $3a^3+6a=b^3$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$. Now the hard part is to prove that there are exactly $2$ integral solutions.

With a change of variables $U=X/Z$ and $V=Y/Z$ followed by a change $U=x/6$ and $V=y/36$, we can look instead at the curve $E':y^2=x^3-648$. This curve has a trivial torsion subgroup and rank $2$, with generators $(18,72)$ and $(9,9)$. Moreover each point $(x,y)$ in $E'$ corresponds to a (projective) point $(x/6:y/36:1)$ on $E$, and a point $(X:Y:Z)$ on $E$ corresponds to a solution $a=Z/Y$ and $b=X/Y$. This means that $E$ is generated by $P_1=(3:2:1)$ and $P_2=(18:3:12)$ which correspond respectively to $(a,b)=(1/2,3/2)$ and $(4,6)$. The origin $(0:1:0)$ corresponds to $(a,b)=(0,0)$.

Now it is a matter of looking through all $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combinations of $P_1$ and $P_2$ to see if any gives another $(a,b)$ integral. However, this is a finite search, because of the way heights of points work, and one can calculate a bound on the height for a point $(a,b)$ to have both integral coordinates. Once this bound is found, a search among a few small linear combinations of $P_1$ and $P_2$ shows that $(0,0)$ and $(4,6)$ are actually the only two possible integral solutions.

Here is another rational solution, not as trivial as the first one I offered, that appears from $P_1-P_2$:
$$\left(-\frac{10}{11}\right)^3 + \left(\frac{1}{11}\right)^3 + \left(\frac{12}{11}\right)^3 = \left(\frac{9}{11}\right)^3 $$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $6a$ instead of $6a^2$?

Comment: About that last solution: That's nice; it contains the cubes for the Hardy–Ramanujan number :-)

Comment: Thanks! Fixed it. Luckily, the projective equation $3Z^3+6ZY^2=X^3$ was correctly written, so the rest is OK.