# $n^3 + (n+1)^3 + (n+2)^3 = m^3$ $\implies$ $4| n+1$?

Tags: number-theory

If $n$ and $m$ are positive integers so that $n^3 + (n+1)^3 + (n+2)^3 = m^3$ , then is it true that $4$ divides $n+1$ ?

Comment: It is easier consider $n+1=t$, and $(t-1)^3+t^3+(t+1)^3=m^3$, or $3t^3+6t=m^3$. Are you sure that your equation has solution???

Comment: @Oleg567, $3^3+4^3+5^3=6^3$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, whoops. Of course.

Comment: Wolfram says $3^3+4^3+5^3=6^3$ is the only solution: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicNumber.html (near equation 29). But this question may not need to find all solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is true, simply because the only solution in positive integers is $3^3+4^3+5^3=6^3$. Already Euler studied this problem. So far no link for a proof was given. So here is a [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120254/sum-of-three-consecutive-cubes). 
There may be also a solution *without* using this, but there seems to be no need for it.